# All possible subsets of set

Tags: r, subset

My environment: Win7 and R 3.1.1 currently.

I have a data set of certain firm's brand and corresponding market share:
(Apple, 0.50), (Nokia, 0.24), (HTC,0.12), (RIM, 0.07), (Palm, 0.03) etc....

So I got a set such as (Apple, Nokia, HTC, RIM,...).

And I want all possible subsets of set which has summation of market share of its components.

For example, a subset (Apple,HTC) with value (0.50+0.12).

How can I realize this idea?

Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: You need to provide more info here - What does your input `data.frame` look like? What about the output? What have you tried?

Comment: Two functions you might find useful: `?expand.grid` and `?combn` - but as John said, more info is necessary to help you

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
# sample data
df <- data.frame(company = c('Apple','Nokia','HTC','RIM','Palm'),
                share = c(.5,.24,.12,.07,.03))

# create index of all combinations
allcombsindex <- lapply(1:nrow(df),function(x){
  combn(1:length(df$company),x,simplify = F)
})
# get rid of extra level
allcombsindex <- do.call('c',allcombsindex)

# paste together company names and sum the shares
result <- sapply(allcombsindex,function(x,y = df){
  c(paste(y$company[x],collapse = ","),
  sum(y$share[x]))
})

# transpose upright with correct classes
data<-as.data.frame(t(result),stringsAsFactors = F)
data$V2 <- as.numeric(data$V2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to ARobertson, I am almost there and here is what I got now.

```
df <- data.frame(company = c('B','m1','m2','m3','m4','m5','m6','m7'),
             share = c(0, 0.235, 0.252, 0.063, 0.073, 0.069, 0.022, 0.286))

# create index of all combinations
allcombsindex <- lapply(1:nrow(df),function(x){
  combn(1:length(df$company),x,simplify = F)
})
# get rid of extra level
allcombsindex <- do.call('c',allcombsindex)

# paste together company names and sum the shares
result <- sapply(allcombsindex,function(x,y = df){
  c(paste(y$company[x],collapse = ","),
    sum(y$share[x]))
})

# transpose upright
data<-as.data.frame(t(result))

# from Factor into Numeric, see the class(data$V2)
as.numeric.factor <- function(x) {as.numeric(levels(x))[x]}

# Define market share summation
m<-as.numeric.factor(data$V2)

# And now good looking data frame 
data_working<-data.frame(data$V1,m)

# the limit repertory
# r=0.5, s=0.75
m0<-0.5*(1-0.75)/(1-0.5*0.75)

data_working2<-data.frame(data_working, m0)
```

---

But I want to progress since this is a half of what I am aiming for.
Firstly, I need to compare the m and m0 in a row of the data_working2.
Secondly, according to the comparison between m and m0, I want to return m or 0.
I already have tried:

```
compare<-function(m,m0){if (m > m0) return(m) else return (0)}

data2<-apply(data1, 1, compare)
```

and It failed. But this one worked!

```
# compare the limit repertoty with existing repertory

compare<-ifelse(data_working2[,2]>data_working2[,3],data_working2[,2],0)
```